# Binding datareader to asp chart control

Tags: c#, asp.net, mschart

Essentially I have a datareader that in theory will call a storedprocedure, and bind the query that is returned to a chart.

This is the data that I'd like to be bound to a chart:

```
ForecastDesc    Previous    Current Budget  Forecast 4  Forecast 7 
Period1 966025.79   1466872.95  1000000.00  0.00    0.00
Period2 1051175.09  1489785.15  1000000.00  0.00    0.00
Period3 1205352.26  1552806.49  1000000.00  0.00    0.00
Period4 1261483.84  1544562.06  1000000.00  50.00   0.00
Period5 1298918.58  1681396.55  1000000.00  45.00   0.00
Period6 1314396.68  1611695.58  10000000.00 50.50   0.00
Period7 1465150.48  1622354.24  1000000.00  50.50   123.00
Period8 1426084.73  1632609.46  1000000.00  50.50   0.00
Period9 1395144.09  370334.88   1000000.00  50.50   0.00
Period10    1347280.57  0.00    1000000.00  50.50   0.00
Period11    1374741.53  0.00    1000000.00  50.50   0.00
Period12    1331704.11  0.00    1000000.00  50.20   0.00
Period13    1367272.27  0.00    1000000.00  50.70   0.00
```

My vb code is as follows:

```
    Protected Sub YearList_SelectedIndexChanged(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As EventArgs) Handles YearList.SelectedIndexChanged

    Chart1.Visible = True

    mySqlConn = New SqlConnection
    mySqlConn.ConnectionString = "Server=" + dbServerName + "; Database=" + dbCatalogName + "; Trusted_Connection=True;"


    pSql = New SqlCommand

    pSql.Connection = mySqlConn
    pSql.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
    pSql.CommandText = "dbo.[sp_DW_Transpose_BudgetForecast]"


    pSql.Parameters.Add("@seg1", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    pSql.Parameters.Add("@seg2", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    pSql.Parameters.Add("@seg3", SqlDbType.NVarChar)
    pSql.Parameters.Add("@year", SqlDbType.NVarChar)

    pSql.Parameters("@seg1").Value = Seg1.SelectedItem.Text
    pSql.Parameters("@seg2").Value = Seg2.SelectedItem.Text
    pSql.Parameters("@seg3").Value = Seg3.SelectedItem.Text
    pSql.Parameters("@year").Value = YearList.SelectedItem.Text

    pSql.Connection.Open()
    pReader = pSql.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.CloseConnection)

    While pReader.Read()
        Chart1.DataBindTable(pReader)
    End While

    pReader.Close()
    pReader = Nothing

    mySqlConn.Close()



End Sub
```

When my web program gets to the point where it is ready to create the chart I get the following error:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Specified method is not supported.

Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web          request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it   originated in the code. 

Exception Details: System.NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.

Source Error: 


Line 111:
Line 112:        While pReader.Read()
Line 113:            Chart1.DataBindTable(pReader)
Line 114:        End While
Line 115:


Stack Trace: 


[NotSupportedException: Specified method is not supported.]
 System.Data.Common.DbEnumerator.Reset() +65
 System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImage.GetDataSourceMemberNames(Object     dataSource, Boolean usedForYValue) +2363
 System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.ChartImage.DataBindTable(IEnumerable dataSource, String xField) +59
 System.Web.UI.DataVisualization.Charting.Chart.DataBindTable(IEnumerable dataSource) +36
 Forecasting.WebForm1.YearList_SelectedIndexChanged(Object sender, EventArgs e) in 
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.ListControl.OnSelectedIndexChanged(EventArgs e) +113
 System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() +143
     System.Web.UI.WebControls.DropDownList.System.Web.UI.IPostBackDataHandler.RaisePostDataChangedEvent() +10
 System.Web.UI.Page.RaiseChangedEvents() +135
 System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean    includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +4867

 Version Information: Microsoft .NET Framework Version:4.0.30319; ASP.NET    Version:4.0.30319.1
```

Anyways Im not sure if Databindtable is the correct method I should be using or maybe even Databindcrosstable. I've been staring at this problem for four days now and am calling upon your expertise to hopefully guide me in the correct direction now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe the problem is you are calling `.DataBindTable()` and passing in a `DataReader`, but DataReader does *not* implement `IEnumerable` and therefore the error about the method not being supported. Try dumping the data into a `DataTable` or `DataSet` and pass that as the parameter to `.DataBindTable()`

[Chart.DataBindTable Method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd455374%28v=vs.100%29.aspx)

Comment: I actually figured out that I didn't need to transpose my data in my stored procedure. I came to transposing before I learned about `databindtable()`. Once I took the transpose out it does display my chart dynamically, but not in the way I am needing to achieve.